# How to login with passphrase?

Tags: gpg

I use GPG a lot so I need to enter my passphrase many times (even though I use gpg-agent).
My issue is that to login on my desktop, I need to enter my user password, then my passphrase.
I wonder if I could only enter my passphrase to go to my desktop.
An idea could be that my user password is encrypted using my public key so I would only need to enter my passphrase.
Are there any support for this using a display manager?
Do you have any other idea that would allow me to only enter my passphrase (my passphrase is needed after login)?

Comment: I've never heard of a display manager that supports what you're suggesting. I would suggest looking at whether there are a GPG module for PAM that allows this,

Comment: Wait, isn't the passphrase to decrypt your home directory?  Or maybe to decrypt the file that contain the key to be piped into cryptsetup to decrypt the home directory?

Comment: The Gnome Keyring Daemon might support this. It used to for sure as GKD had its own GPG agent which was unlocked by PAM on login. But this custom GPG agent [was removed](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/distributor-list/2015-August/msg00000.html). However I'm not sure if GKD still managed to keep the unlock behavior, and is just integrating with the official GPG agent instead of using its own.

Comment: @grochmal No, it is not to decrypt the home directory; it is to decrypt passwords (using the `pass` utility) used by some applications.

Comment: @Henrik I am not necessarily looking for such a display manager. That could also be a screen locker that I need to enter my passphrase instead of my password that is runned at login with automatic login.

Comment: I only mentioned display managers because you had in the question. A solution using PAM should also affect screen lockers - but I haven't tried I just mentioned PAM in a comment to offer you a search word if you hadn't already explored that way.